# Sort stdClass object by its index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I've seen a million similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them, that I can find, deal with sorting the actual index value of the object.

I have a standard object that I've given a value ($vid) to sort instead of it populating incrementally itself.

```
foreach ($array_videos as $v) {
            $govideo = $this->staff_model->get_video($v->vid);
            $goforit[$v->vid] = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getInfo', array('video_id' => $govideo->video_id));
}
```

When I do this I receive the following output:

```
[33] => stdClass Object ...
[12] => stdClass Object ...
[55] => stdClass Object ...
[61] => stdClass Object ...
```

I would like to sort this array of objects by the object index, ASC or DESC. For example:

```
[61] => stdClass Object ...
[55] => stdClass Object ...
[33] => stdClass Object ...
[12] => stdClass Object ...
```

I've tried ksort and some various usort functions. Can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What issue did you have with `ksort`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) will do the trick:

```
ksort($array_videos);
```

ksort will sort the array keys in `ASC`. you could quickly reverse the order using [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
$array_videos = array_reverse($array_videos);
```

for your real world example you could do one of the following:

```
foreach (ksort($array_videos) as $v)
```

or

```
foreach (array_reverse(ksort($array_videos)) as $v)
```

**Better Yet!!**
to reverse the sort to `DESC` as per the recommendations by [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505722/jim), you can use [krsort()](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505722/jim):

```
ksort($array_videos); //ASC
krsort($array_videos); //DESC
```

Comment: There is a [krsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) which sorts by key in reverse order.

Comment: good call. you would think they would just have an optional flag for reverse instead of using the sort() flags.